# How to boot from a flash drive?

Tags: boot, usb, windows-7

I've installed Ubuntu on a Surface (which no longer has windows). That was an accident. Now I am trying to reinstall Windows over Ubuntu. Eventually, I'd like to successfully dual-boot Windows and Ubuntu on this thing.

I have a bootable flash drive with Windows 7 on it, but how do I get GRUB to boot from it? I've searched for a while, but I only see "Create bootable flash drive!" instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't boot a live system from GRUB, but rather from the BIOS' boot device selection menu.

Microsoft gives an [instruction](http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/storage-files-and-folders/boot-surface-pro-from-usb-recovery-device) on how to do this. It cuts down to these points:

1. Press and old the volume down button and press the Power button
2. Release the volume down button as the Surface logo shows up and it should automatically boot the USB stick.

Windows 7 will most likely not acknowledge the existence of any non-windows-supported file system, like EXT4, which is used for Ubuntu by default. So you may have to reinstall Ubuntu after that.

Comment: Ah, I figured I'd have to reinstall Ubuntu. When I follow those instructions, though, I get taken immediately to the GRUB menu; no boot menu or anything.

Comment: Else, you could use GRUB's shell (press 'c' while in the menu) to boot the Windows installer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/211024/how-can-i-boot-into-windows-from-grub-rescue-without-a-cd-drive. You may have to replace `(hd2,0)` with the appropriate partition of your USB (GRUB command `ls`)

Answer (score -1):

Most probably you will need to use GParted to create a partition for your Windows OS and set it as NTFS or FAT32 so Windows can recognize the partition where to install it.